# need html and javascript testing code for Secugen Hamster pro2o

Tags: javascript, html, fingerprint

I'm using Secugen Hamster pro2o for finger print.I already installed all driver related to secugen hamster.Now i need html and javascript code for testing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ActiveX Example 1.1 of SecuGen FDx Pro SDK </title>

<script lang=javascript>
<!--
var aaa = 0;
function fnOpenDevice()
{
    document.frmmain.objFP.DeviceID = document.frmmain.inc.value;
    document.frmmain.objFP.CodeName = document.frmmain.dev.value;
    document.frmmain.objFP.MinutiaeMode = document.frmmain.templateFormat.value;

    // template format of objVerify should be the same to those of objFP[]
    objVerify.MinutiaeMode = document.frmmain.templateFormat.value;
    return;
}

function fnCapture()
{
    document.frmmain.objFP.Capture();
    var result = document.frmmain.objFP.ErrorCode;
alert(result);
    if (result == 0)
    {   
        //var strimg1 = objFP.ImageTextData;    
        var strmin = document.frmmain.objFP.MinTextData;
alert(strmin);
        document.frmmain.min.value = strmin;
    }
    else
        alert('failed - ' + result);

    return;
}

function fnRegister()
{
    var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
    var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[1].value;

    if ( objVerify.RegisterForText(strmin1, strmin2) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0 )
        alert('success- registered');
    else
        alert('failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

    return;
}

function fnVerifyEx()
{   
    var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
    var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[1].value;
    var strmin3 = document.frmmain.min[2].value;

    if ( objVerify.VerifyExForText(strmin1, strmin2, strmin3) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0)
        alert('Success - matched');
    else
        alert('Failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

    return;
}

function fnVerify()
{   
    var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
    var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[2].value;

    if ( objVerify.VerifyForText(strmin1, strmin2) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0 )
        alert('Success - matched');
    else
        alert('Failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

    return;
}

function fnSetimage()
{
    document.frmmain.objFP.ImageTextData = document.frmmain.img1.value;

    return;
}
// -->

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h4><b>ActiveX Example 1.1 of SecuGen FDx Pro SDK</b></h4>
<p></p>

<OBJECT id=objVerify style="LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" height=0 width=0 
    classid="CLSID:8D613732-7D38-4664-A8B7-A24049B96117" 
    name=objVerify VIEWASTEXT>
</OBJECT>

<form name=frmmain>

Device Type :
<select name=dev>
<option value=0>FDP02
<option value=1>FDU02
<option value=2>FDU03
<option value=3>FDU04
<option selected value=4>FDU05

</select>

Instance No. :
<select name=inc>
<option value=-1>-1 
<option value=0>0
<option value=1>1
<option value=2>2
<option value=3>3
<option value=4>4
<option value=5>5
<option value=6>6
<option value=7>7
<option value=8>8
<option value=9>9
</select>

<p>
Template Format:
<select name=templateFormat>
<option value=256>ANSI 378
<option value=512>SG 400
<option value=768>ISO 19794-2
</select>

<input type=button name=open value='Open Device' OnClick='fnOpenDevice();'>
<p>

<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<caption> Fingerprint Images </caption>
<tr>
<td>
    <OBJECT id=objFP style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 149px; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 182px" height=182 
        width=149 classid="CLSID:D547FDD7-82F6-44e8-AFBA-7553ADCEE7C8" name=objFP VIEWASTEXT>
    <PARAM NAME="CodeName" VALUE="1">
    </OBJECT>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=center><input type=button name=btnCapture1 value='Capture' OnClick='fnCapture();'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>

min1 : <input type=text id=min name=min><br>
<p>
<input type=button name=btnRegister value='Register' OnClick='fnRegister();' style='width:200px'>
<br>
<input type=button name=btnVerify value='VerifyEx' OnClick='fnVerifyEx();' style='width:200px'>
<br>
<input type=button name=btnVerify value='Verify' OnClick='fnVerify();' style='width:200px'>

</form>
<script>
fnOpenDevice();
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Do we need any specific library to run this code or this code works normally?